# jquery mobile tables alternative

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've been trying out tables in my jquery mobile projects but they don't look right.

Lists look fine but I need to be able to add Headings and then different rows.

So, whats the best tables alternative for JQuery Mobile please?

Comment: And what is wrong with tables there?

Comment: Tables just dont look mobile right. Unless you know of a way (Not just the width %).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to stick with [lists](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/docs-lists.html) there are different ways to divided the lists up you should look at inset lists i think that's what you want list dividers may be the way to go for you not really sure what look your going for

Comment: I've had a look at it and I cannot find it has any columns or headings for multiple record views.

Answer (score 3):

Well there is a [Grid Layout](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/content/content-grids.html) as well, but lists can be [styled in many different ways](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/content/../../docs/lists/index.html).

Could you tell us what you're exactly looking for?

Comment: Those are good links but a table is really not that much like a list. Well, it's like a really special kind of list.

Comment: you will have to look at the source but jQM does offer a table structure you can use even though it's not documented very well: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/content/content-html.html (View Source) Example is at the bottom

Comment: OK yes, that's true.  I've just been looking into jQuery mobile (fairly frantically in fact) so that's how I found your answer :-)  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Agreed - jquery mobile still has poor table support ([Sencha Touch](http://www.sencha.com/products/touch) is better in this regard if [tables/grids](http://www.mitchellsimoens.com/Sencha-Projects/demos/) are super important to you).

You could try integrating a table/grid plugin (pretty good discussion on those [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159025/jquery-grid-recommendations)), but beware that jquery mobile's CSS attributes conflict with those of jquery-ui themes, and many plugins use jquery-ui.

Answer (score 1):

use the foo tables. worked great for me.

http://fooplugins.com/footable-demos/ 
http://css-tricks.com/footable-a-jquery-plugin-for-responsive-data-tables/

download [here](https://github.com/bradvin/FooTable)